# How to pass a compile time array with var length to a constructor?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I have the following code:

```
struct MyArrayEntry
{
    int type;
    int id;
};

template<size_t arraySize>
struct MyArray
{
    template<typename T, typename... Types>
    MyArray(T t, Types... ts) : data{ { t, ts... } } {}
    int dataSize = arraySize;
    MyArrayEntry data[arraySize];
};


void Blah()
{
 static MyArray<3> kTest
            (
                { 1, 4 },
                { 2, 5 },
                { 3, 6 }
            );
}
```

But this fails to build with:

> error C2661: 'MyArray<3>::MyArray': no overloaded function takes 3
>   arguments

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not use a  [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) of `MyArrayEntry`? Or why not a [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or even [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? Then your class would be even simpler.

Comment: I don't want a vector because I want to avoid the dynamic allocation. As for array its because I have a field  int dataSize = arraySize; which I also require.

Comment: If you have the array-size as a template argument, why do you also need it as a member variable? Whenever the number of elements will be used you can use `arraySize` directly. Or use the `sizeof` operator on the array. Or if you use `std::array` then it will have a `size()` member function you could use as well. Maybe we could help you with better solutions if we knew what the *real* problem this structure is supposed to solve?

Comment: The compiler has no idea what to do with `{ 1, 4 }`. It is probably meant to initialise an object of some type, but what type is it?

Comment: Its for interop with a 3rd party C library that I can't change. So the memory layout has to be 32bit for the size. And then the 32/32bit pair elements that follow.

Comment: The type is supposed to be MyArrayEntry

Comment: Really? Why? How can you explain that to a compiler?

Comment: I have declared the type in the MyArray class to be MyArrayEntry data[arraySize]; how else would you do it?

Comment: data is unrelated to your function template declaration. C++ doesn't do module-wide type inference. Template parameters of a function template are deduced only from actual arguments at the call site. Not from a function body and not from anywhere else.

Comment: So I should use MyArrayEntry { 1, 4 } in the constructor arguments?

Comment: You could have your class constructor accept an `std::initialiser_list<MyArrayEntry>`, like every good little obedient container does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the imformation you provide, I would suggest using a [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) and an [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) call:

```
template<size_t arraySize>
struct MyArray
{
    const int dataSize = arraySize;  // Could as well make it constant
    MyArrayEntry data[arraySize];

    MyArray(std::initializer_list<MyArrayEntry> elements)
    {
        std::copy(begin(elements), end(elements), std::begin(data));
    }
};
```

Create as

```
MyArray<3> kTest({ { 1, 4 }, { 2, 5 }, { 3, 6 } });
```

Sure it's an extra pair of curly-brackets `{}`, but it will make your code simpler.

Comment: I did try initializer_list initially - I didn't realized you had to copy the data though which kind of sucks. I was trying to pass the initializer_list directly into  data